# Dialogflow bot telegram integration

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I had a bot active on telegram but now I want to change the API token but whenever I'm trying to stop it, it shows a error message . How do I fix it?

> com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException:
> {"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the nature of your error.
My advise is to use Voximplant Dialogflow ES integration so you can add your Telegram bot (or other channels) to be answered by your DF agent very easy.

It's my best way to deal with multiple channels with just one DF agent.

Voximplant integrations are way easier than Dialogflow's native APIs and SDKs.

Check this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QCN0IXVpQ8

The docs - https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/Channels/Telegram

I Hope it's still of help!